# Map Reduce Job: Protobuf related error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, protocol-buffers

I am getting an error while running a `Map Reduce` job:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnProtos$LocalResourceProto.hashLong(J)I
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnProtos$LocalResourceProto.hashCode(YarnProtos.java:11655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.LocalResourcePBImpl.hashCode(LocalResourcePBImpl.java:62)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:362)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:492)
```

Doing a little google search, I bumped into a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/-pwIkGzpsQs), which suggested this as `proto` version related error. It says that my application is having a dependency on `proto3` with yarn using `proto2`.

According to my `pom.xml`, `protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar` is being used.

Can anyone please help me understand the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that the jar file used when the code was *compiled* is different from the jar file used when it was *run*. You need to make sure that you're using exactly the same version of the protobuf jar as the code was compiled against. If you didn't compile the code yourself, you'll need to figure out what version the provider used.